# Create contact or update existing one depending if they already exist

Tags: php

I'm using [Send In Blue](https://www.sendinblue.com/) to keep track of my contacts. Throughout my site I'm either updating the contact or creating a new one but I've never had to combine the two. I have my pieces of code separately below.

**How can I combine the two so that if there's a user there already then it updates them and if not then it creates them?**

Is it possible to update first and if that fails create them?

```
try {
$updateContact = new \SendinBlue\Client\Model\UpdateContact($data);

    $result = $SendInBlue->updateContact($email, $updateContact);
    return true;

} catch (Exception $e) {
}
```

And this is the code to create a contact:

```
try {
$createContact = new \SendinBlue\Client\Model\CreateContact($data);

    $result = $SendInBlue->createContact($email, $createContact);
    return true;

} catch (Exception $e) {
}
```

Comment: _"Is it possible to update first and if that fails create them?"_ - That seems like a pretty easy thing to test? Just try it and see if it works.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm not familiar with `try`, does it work the same way as an if/else statement?

Comment: Sounds like a perfect time to read up on Exceptions and how to handle them: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: According the [the API docs](https://developers.sendinblue.com/reference#createcontact), there's an `updateEnabled` option that can be set when attempting to create.

Comment: @PatrickQ Ah that could do it, so I can remove my update function and just use the create function. How can I enable that in the syntax I have? I'm already struggling with it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the `updateContact()` and just use `createContact()` because the is an `updateEnabled` option that can be set during the creation attempt.  The purpose of this option is to "Facilitate to update the existing contact in the same request (updateEnabled = true)"

You can either set this while creating the `CreateContact` object ...

```
$data["updateEnabled"] = true;
$createContact = new \SendinBlue\Client\Model\CreateContact($data);
```

Or by using the `setUpdateEnabled()` method ...

```
try {
$createContact = new \SendinBlue\Client\Model\CreateContact($data);
$createContact->setUpdateEnabled(true);

    $result = $SendInBlue->createContact($email, $createContact);
    return true;

} catch (Exception $e) {
}
```

For reference, [here](https://github.com/sendinblue/APIv3-php-library/blob/master/lib/Model/CreateContact.php) is the code for the `CreateContact` class that you're using, and [here](https://developers.sendinblue.com/reference#createcontact) is the documentation for the raw SendInBlue API.

Comment: Great thanks, I'd attempted something similar to the first option but it didn't work... the second option works perfectly though.

Comment: You're welcome.  If you had tried something that didn't work, but you felt should have, based on the documentation, that probably would have made for a better question.

Comment: Sorry I had an attempt after your last comment... you'd written the answer by the time I came back.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to check if contact exist or not for that, you can use this metod getContactInfo(emailidentifier) if it returns true, then you can update the contact : UpdateContact() if return false then you can create a contact : CreateContact().